# Without header(stdio.h) file, how can the following code run?

Tags: c

How this following code can run without including header file for printf function?

```
int main(){
printf("%d",1);
return 0;}
```

Comment: What compiler? What IDE are you using?

Comment: 1. You ignored compiler diagnostics. 2. The behavior is undefined. That's how it "runs", if you can call it that.

Comment: I am using GCC version 5.4.0 which is preinstalled in my Linux os.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** This is a hand-wavy answer that will *roughly* be correct. Someone else who knows the gory details (for gcc, e.g.) may enlighten both of us. Here goes:

Because in C — at least for some compilers — implicitly defined functions are fine. So it compiles it, then hands it off to the linker. It sees a reference to `printf`, and since the linker by default links with the C runtime library, it will resolve that symbol to the correct function.

I guess an implicit function like that will get a default signature, typically expecting to return an int. As for the arguments to the function, those can't be type checked at compile time, because the compiler doesn't know what the actual function signature is. So it will just use standard calling convention, e.g. pass arguments by registers or something like that.

Comment: what standards? Its not in C99 anyway and would constitute an error.

Comment: OK, I guess it should say "some compilers" then. Thanks

Comment: Technically, calling a varags function like `printf()` without a prototype in scope was undefined behaviour even in C90.  In practice, you usually got away with it, but it was never standards conforming.  Change the function from `printf()` to `puts()`, for example, and it was OK in C90, though not recommended.